# Name of submit buttons in array and identifying the index of clicked button

Tags: php, html

Multiple submit buttons will be created for my html page dynamically depending on the searched query. When clicked on a particular button, it will open the same page as the other buttons. So i have assigned submit buttons names an array. I need to identify which submit button is clicked using php. Basically i want to find the array index of the submit button clicked.

Comment: I dont know how many submit buttons will be there. The no of submit buttons depends entirely on the no of rows fetched by a sql query.

Comment: You could use a hidden input that has the id of the clicked submit button.

Comment: How exactly? I dont have much idea about hidden inputs?

Comment: I can write you an example.

Comment: Sure... That would be really helpful..

Comment: All of my submit button will open the same html page. By assigning button with array index name, I'm trying to set a particular session variable with value depending on the button clicked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an hidden input to keep track of the clicked submit button.

```
// First create an HTML hidden input
<input id="the_clicked_id" type="hidden" name="the_clicked_id" value=""/>

// It's a bit ugly, but all your submits would need an onclick event
// and an ID. They are easily added with PHP tho
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < $some_length; $i++) {
        echo "<input id=\"submit_$i\" name=\"submit_$i\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" onclick=\"return myId(this);\"/>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
?>

// Javascript side
myId = function (element) {
    document.getElementById('the_clicked_id').value = element.id;
    return true;
}
```

Then you can access this new value (holding the clicked submit button id) PHP side with

```
$clicked_id = $_POST['the_clicked_id'];
// or
$clicked_id = $_GET['the_clicked_id'];
```

Let me know if you need me to edit the answer.

Comment: i need to use a for loop for the creation of multiple submit button depending on sql output. How will i assign names to the different submit button.?

Comment: Just like I did for ID's let me update.

Comment: i typed this in the php page:       <?php
$clicked_id = $_POST['the_clicked_id'];
echo $clicked_id;
?>              Bt i'm getting this error: undefined index: the_clicked_id

Comment: Did you add the hidden input inside your form ?

Comment: I dint... By the way, Thank you so very much . All because of you my query is resolved. I was stuck in this problem since a long time. Thank you again :)

Comment: NP have a nice day :)